# Quick Sort Error, Possibly an off by 1 C++

Tags: c++, quicksort, off-by-one

Trying to write a quick sort and have spent awhile debugging. The problem seems to be in the second recursive call, but I can't figure out where I'm off. Any pointer would be awesome. Thanks.

```
void quickSort(vector<int> &list, int left, int right){

    int pivot = left;
    int temp = right;

    if(left >= right - 1)
        return;

    while (left != right) {
        if (pivot == left){
            if (list[pivot] > list[right]) {
                //-------------------------
                int tempList = list[right];
                list[right] = list[pivot];   // Swap for now
                list[pivot] = tempList;
                //-------------------------
                pivot = right;
                left++;
            }else{
                right--;
            }

        }else{
            if (list[pivot] < list[left]) {
                //-------------------------
                int tempList = list[left];
                list[left] = list[pivot];   // Swap for now
                list[pivot] = tempList;
                //-------------------------
                pivot = left;
                right--;
            }else{
                left++;
            }
        }
    }
    quickSort(list, 0, right-1);
    quickSort(list, right + 1, temp);
}
```

This is how I'm making the data set right now:

```
srand(time(0));
vector<int> list;
vector<int> sortedList;
int i;
for (i=0;i<10;i++) list.push_back(rand() %100);
```

I got a data set of          38         65         26         22         86         64         13         28         57         18

and got an output of         13        18        22        26        28        38        57        64        86        65

It's usually an element in the last half, but it's also not every time. Maybe 1 in 4 times.

Comment: I updated with more details. The error only occurs once every few times. Maybe 1 in 4 on average.

Comment: Rather than testing against random data, setup unit tests that test scenarios of increasing complexity. You would have a better way to understand and reproduce any failure. If you have a random data set that caused the error, set up a test that uses that data set every time.

Comment: @Bargangilo - I would also refrain from naming your parameter `list` due to an already existing `std::list` template class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are accessing elements at location `right` and `left` I assume that the initial call is as follows:

```
quickSort(list, 0, list.size()-1);
```

If the list is initially initialized as `vector<int>{ 2, 1 }` the first call will evalute to

```
quickSort(list, 0, 1);
```

With `left=0` and `right=1` the first `if`-statement will evaluate to

```
    if(0 >= 1-1)
        return;
```

and the function will return without swapping the two elements, even if the list is clearly unsorted.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed my functions end condition to `if(left >= right) {return;}` and it's working every time now.